# Running child class tests dependent on parent does not work (TestNG, IntelliJ)

Tags: java, maven, selenium, intellij-idea

I am having trouble running tests in a subclass in IntelliJ.  This seems to work when I run the build through maven, but trying to run the child class in IntelliJ causes the child test to get ignored.  Here is an example:

The parent class:

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.testng.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.testng.Assert.fail;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestSomething {

    @Test
    public void runSomething(){
        //Test Stuff
    }
}
```

And the child class:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

public class TestThisSomethingAsWell extends TestSomething{

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "runSomething")
    public void runSomethingElse(){
        //More Test Stuff
    }
}
```

In the above example, both runSomething and runSomethingElse get called when running through Maven, but when I run the TestThisSomethingAsWell class through IntelliJ only runSomething is run.  It does not even show runSomethingElse in the list of tests.

Also note that these are selenium tests, but I am not sure if that is part of the problem or not.

Edit:  Added import statements.

Comment: How are you invoking the tests when running through maven? xml?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you are using TestNG, and not JUnit, when running through IntelliJ?

Comment: @niharika_neo:  I have an xml file for the test suite.  The "TestSomething" class is not called in the xml file, only the TestThisSomethingAsWell" class.

Comment: @SiKing:  It is a TestNG configuration, not a JUnit.  Junit isn't even used in the project.

Comment: Could you also show your `import`s?